# How to create a simple pascal-program in Codegear RAD Studio 2009?

Tags: delphi

For example, this simple program:

```
Program Helloworld;
Begin
  writeln ('Hello world!');
  readln;
End;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Select "File|New|Other..." - the "New Items" Dialog appears
2. Select "Delphi Projects" on the left panel
3. Select "Console Application" on the right panel
4. Click "OK" button.

That is all.

Answer (score 3):

You can get rid of all the forms that a new project creates, and just have a program in the project file.

This looks like a console app so you'll want to do some steps. This is taken from the excellent [delphi.about.com](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/l/aa091101a.htm):

> 1. Select "File | New Application"
> 2. Select "Project | Remove From Project..."
> 3. Select Unit1 (Form1) and click OK. Delphi will remove the selected unit
>      from the uses clause of the current
>      project.
> 4. Select "Project | View Source"
> 5. Edit your project source file: • Delete all the code inside "begin" and
>      "end". • After the uses keyword,
>      replace the "Forms" unit with
>      "SysUtils". • Place {$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
>      right under the "program" statement.

Comment: What's wrong with "File | New other ... | Console Application"?

Comment: I wasn't sure this option was available in all versions of Delphi so I gave an answer that would be suitable if it wasn't there.

Comment: For future info: the menu option to create a new console app has been in the Delphi and C++ Builder IDEs since version 1 of both.